# postbank_pdf2csv: how to setup with Cygwin in Windows?

Tags: bash, postbank-pdf2csv

I wanted to convert some Postbank PDFs to CSV and found [Postbank_PDF2CSV](https://github.com/FlatheadV8/Postbank_PDF2CSV) which is based on command line utils and bash-script-based parsing.
I wanted to try it out with Cygwin under Windows since I had no other Linux at hand and was quite positive it would work.

It did not work right away and greeted me with:

```
$ ./postbank_pdf2csv_bis_2023-02.sh -?
Dieses Skript funktioniert nur mit FreeBSD, Linux or Macos.
```

I tried to remove the overjealous restriction, installed some required libs, fixed some script bug (that exited the script before CSV generation and echoing `hallo`) but could not make it work getting errors like:

`GPL Ghostscript 10.01.2: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1`

Although I have a github account I could not file an issue or get in contact at the project itself.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I could make it work and I want to share important steps that should help to get it done or make it into the scripts and wiki of the project:

1. install *Cygwin* and add `wget` command in the process to download some package manager
2. download and install `apt-cyg` for easier tool install without using `setup.exe`:

   ```
   $ wget rawgit.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg/master/apt-cyg
   $ install apt-cyg /bin
   ```
3. make the **internal script-os-check** in `postbank_pdf2csv*.sh` **run under Cygwin by adding some code** here:

   - old:
     `if [ "$(uname -o)" = "FreeBSD"  ] || [ "$(uname -o)" = "Darwin" ] ; then`
   - new:
     `if [ "$(uname -o)" = "FreeBSD"  ] || [ "$(uname -o)" = "Darwin" ]  || [ "$(uname -o)" = "Cygwin" ] ; then`
4. in some history version scripts there is some **test code** that causes some early `exit` of the script which can be fixed by **outcommenting (`#`) those lines**, e.g.:

   ```
   #echo 'hallo'
   #exit
   ```
5. **`README.md`** says to install some **required tools** and we do it like this:

   `$ apt-cyg install  ghostscript  poppler  pstotext`
6. different errors arise because of still missing libraries so in summary I fixed it like this:

   - the typical error is
     `C:/cygwin64/bin/pdftotext.exe: error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`
   - to determine the missing libraries you could check iteratively the missing ones running `cygcheck` on it, e.g.:
     `$ cygcheck /usr/bin/pdftotext.exe`
     which may result in e.g.:

   ```
   C:\cygwin64\bin\pdftotext.exe

     C:\cygwin64\bin\cygpoppler-106.dll
       C:\cygwin64\bin\cygwin1.dll
         C:\Windows\system32\KERNEL32.dll
           C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-17.0.2.8-hotspot\bin\api-ms-win-core-rtlsupport-l1-1-0.dll
           C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
           C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
   ...
         C:\cygwin64\bin\cygssh2-1.dll
           C:\cygwin64\bin\cygcrypto-1.1.dll
         C:\cygwin64\bin\cygzstd-1.dll
   cygcheck: track_down: could not find cygfontconfig-1.dll

   cygcheck: track_down: could not find cygfreetype-6.dll

   cygcheck: track_down: could not find cygjpeg-8.dll

   cygcheck: track_down: could not find cyglcms2-2.dll

   cygcheck: track_down: could not find cygnspr4.dll

   cygcheck: track_down: could not find cygnss3.dll

   cygcheck: track_down: could not find cygopenjp2-7.dll

   cygcheck: track_down: could not find cygplc4.dll

   cygcheck: track_down: could not find cygpng16-16.dll

   cygcheck: track_down: could not find cygsmime3.dll

   cygcheck: track_down: could not find cygtiff-6.dll
   ```

   - **lib dependency solution** for me was:
     `$ apt-cyg install  libpoppler106  libfontconfig1  libfreetype6  libjpeg8  liblcms2_2 libnspr4  libnss3  libopenjp2_7  libpng16  libtiff6  libdeflate0  libjbig2  libwebp7  libexpat1  libgs10  libX11_6  libXt6  libpaper1  libtiff7  libxcb1  libICE6  libSM6  libXau6  libXdmcp6  libiconv`
7. if you get the above error `GPL Ghostscript 10.01.2: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1` I fixed it by **moving my PDFs to some local drive** (`C:`) while it was a mapped remote one before (network share)